# Criar Foreign Key hibernate

Tags: java

Solucionado e editado da meneira correta:

Não consigo incluir uma nota fiscal com o id do cliente. Neste caso o cliente pode ter várias notas fiscais atribuídas a ele.

Estou conseguindo cadastrar a NF corretamente, mas não mostra o número do cliente que esta nota fiscal está vinculada, no BD aparece o id, número da nf, data e valor porém não aparece o número do cliente a quem ela pertence.

No cadastro do cliente aparece o campo número da nota fiscal e o valor é `null`.

Seguem os arquivos:

**NotaFiscal**

```
@Entity
public class NotaFiscal implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String numero;
    private Double valor;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

   public NotaFiscal() {

   }
```

//incluir os getter e setter do cliente no arquivo notaFiscal

**Cliente**

```
@Entity
 public class Cliente {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;        
private String nome;    
private String sobrenome;
@Email
@NotBlank
@Column(unique=true)
private String email;
private String senha;    
private String cpf;    
private String cep;    
private String endereco;    
private String numero;    
private String bairro;    
private String cidade;    
private String estado;
private String ddd;    
private String celular;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente")
  private Set<NotaFiscal> notas;


public Cliente() {
}
```

**NotaFiscalBean**

```
@Model
public class NotaFiscalBean {


private NotaFiscal notaFiscal = new NotaFiscal();
@Inject
private NotaFiscalDAO notaFiscalDAO;
@Inject
private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

private Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
private Long idCliente;




@Transactional
public void gravar() {

     Cliente cliente = clienteDAO.buscaPorId(idCliente);
     notaFiscal.setCliente(cliente );
     notaFiscalDAO.adiciona(notaFiscal);

    clienteDAO.save(cliente);

    this.notaFiscal = new NotaFiscal();

    this.setCliente(new Cliente());

    idCliente = null;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h:form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nomecliente" class="col-sm-8 col-form-label">
            Identificação do Cliente (digite o numero do cliente)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><br></br>
            <h:inputText  id="nomecliente" value="# 
               {notaFiscalBean.idCliente}" type="number" class="form- 
       control"  
       a:autofocus="true" />
        </div>
    </div>

<h:commandButton value="Cadastrar" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" 
   action="#{notaFiscalBean.gravar}"></h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

**notaFiscalDAO**

```
public class NotaFiscalDAO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

public void adiciona(NotaFiscal nota) {
    manager.persist(nota);
}

public List<NotaFiscal> listaTodos() {
    CriteriaQuery<NotaFiscal> query = 
manager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(NotaFiscal.class);
    query.select(query.from(NotaFiscal.class));

    List<NotaFiscal> lista = manager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    return lista; 
}

public int contaTodos() {
    long result = (Long) manager.createQuery("select count(n) from 
     NotaFiscal n").getSingleResult();

    return (int) result;
}

public List<NotaFiscal> listaTodosPaginada(int firstResult, int maxResults) 
{
    CriteriaQuery<NotaFiscal> query = 
     manager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(NotaFiscal.class);
    query.select(query.from(NotaFiscal.class));

    List<NotaFiscal> lista = 
   manager.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(firstResult)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();

    return lista;
}

 }
```

**ClienteDAO** buscando o id do cliente no BD

```
public Cliente buscaPorId(Long id) {

    Cliente cliente = manager.find(Cliente.class, id);

    return cliente;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo um mapeamento errado, quando diz que um cliente pode ter várias notas fiscais então o correto é a nota fiscal ter apenas um cliente e não uma lista de cliente, ao invés de usar o OneToMany (muitos clientes pode ter uma nota), use o ManyToOne (muitas notas pode ter um mesmo cliente), ficaria assim:

**Entidade nota fiscal:**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_cliente")
private Cliente cliente
```

**Entidade cliente**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente")
private Set<NotaFiscal> notas;
```

Obs: para fazer o mapeamento das notas no cliente, recomendo usar a estrutura de dados `Set` ao invés do `List`, pois ela já garante que não haverá duas entidades identicas na collection.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno Adriano, entendi, fiz as alterações e consigo cadastrar a nota fiscal no BD não houve erro,  mas ao consultar a tabela nota fiscal o campo id_cliente aparece null e acredito que deveria aparecer o id do cliente, não seria isso?. Você saberia me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Posta o método completo que vc está usando para salvar.

Comment: obrigado Adriano, editei o post e incluí os arquivos se precisar de mais alguma coisa me avisa que eu posto.

Comment: Oi Adriano resolvido. Depois de muito testar e alterar encontrei a solução. O NULL era causado pela falta do getter e setter do cliente no arquivo notaFiscal. O restante com as mudanças que você me orientou funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!